# Division by zero, "Query was empty" error in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search-engine

I try to make a search engine for profiles, but I stock with an error that "Division by zero" and and after I used var_dump(mysql_error()) it shows me "Query was Empty".

here is my query and php code:

```
$search_rs = dbq('SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE '%$_GET[query]%' LIMIT 0, OR fname LIKE '%$_GET[query]%'');
            if($search_rs == false) {
                    var_dump(mysql_error());
                }
         elseif (db_num($search_rs) > 0) {

                while ($results = db_next($search_rs)) {

                echo('<li>
                            <a class="avatar" href="http://mysite/'.$results['pagekey'].'" target="_blank">
                                <img src="'.thumbnail($results['avatar'], 64, 64).'" />
                            </a>
                            <div class="info">
                                <a href="http://profiler.ir/'.$results['pagekey'].'" target="_blank">
                                    <span class="fullname">'.$results['pre_name'].' '.$results['fname'].' '.$results['lname'].'</span>
                                </a> 
                            </div>
                      </li>  ');
     }
}
else echo "not found !!!";
```

BUT When I remove `LIKE '%$_GET[query]%'`and make a simple query without `LIKE` , it return results.

Comment: Once you properly quote/concatenate your string for the query this will work, you will also have a gaping SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: You should not just dump your code, but remove unnecessary code.

Answer (score 2):

Change your query from this:

```
'SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE '%$_GET[query]%' LIMIT 0, OR fname LIKE '%$_GET[query]%''
```

To this:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE '%" . $_GET['query'] . "%'"
```

The issues you had were:

- Using single quotes for the whole query string as well as the `LIKE '%…%'` values inside of them. So using double quotes now, concatenating the values.
- You also had missing single quotes for your `$_GET[query]` so those are changed to `$_GET['query']`.
- The placement of `LIMIT 0,` makes no sense so that is gone.
- Also unsure why you had two `fname LIKE '%" . $_GET['query'] . "%'` in there. Removed the second one.

If you somehow need the `LIMIT` then this query should work:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE '%" . $_GET['query'] . "%' LIMIT 0,100"
```

But I am just presuming you need 100 items, so change that `100` as well as the `0` offset to best match your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL error is caused by malformed SQL text. The problem in the code is that the desired SQL text isn't being produced, due to the PHP syntax for interpreting/concatenating strings.

I recommend you use double quotes around the literal portions of the string, and use a dot operator to signify concatenation.

I also recommend you do the string manipulation as a separate step, so that the SQL text is available for inspection/debugging.

I also strongly recommend you use the **`mysql_real_escape_string`** function to reduce SQL injection vulnerabilities (when including user supplied data within the SQL text).

As an example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[query]) . "%'";
#vardump($sql);  # for inspecting/debugging issues with generating SQL text
$search_rs = dbq($sql);
```

---

Little Bobby Tables XKCD [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)